Computing pseudo-threshold with sinter and stim
I've been using stim and sinter to test some codes I've been developing. Is there a built in sinter method for approximating the pseudothreshold? I could fit a curve to my data and find where it intersects with the y=x line, but it's not obvious to me what function to fit it too.

There's no method in stim or sinter for computing a pseudothreshold. In general, stim and sinter do very little analysis and instead focus on providing basic tools that can be part of a larger analysis.
